# How can I allow styling text inside a Word form field?

Tags: microsoft-word, forms

I have a Microsoft Word document with some legacy form fields. If I add the editing restriction "*Allow only... Filling in forms*" and start enforcing protection then I can enter text into the legacy text form fields. However, the text has to be completely unformatted: I can't use italics, superscript, preset styles, etc. Even if I paste in styled text from another Word document, all of the formatting is stripped.

Curiously, if I select some text inside the field and then click the "*Stop protection*" button, I can style it, so it's not that the legacy text form field is unable to contain formatted text.

I would solve the problem by replacing the legacy field with a non-legacy rich text field, but I need to retain the ability to save as a Word 97-2003 document because some of the people who will be filling in the form work in organisations whose sysadmins are very slow to upgrade, and that's out of my control.

Is there a way to restrict editing to the legacy form fields but to allow that editing to include applying formatting?